# Why does a .sh file's md5sum change when copying to another folder?

Tags: downloads, scp, md5sum

I have downloaded a sh file from a webpage. I want to copy it to another machine so I can install it there. The other machine is an imx6 tiny rex. I tried to copy/move/scp to my Ubuntu machine to the other one and it seems to be okay, but as soon as I try to execute it, it does a md5 comparison telling that md5 has changed and stopping the process.

I tried to move to another folder inside my Ubuntu machine and I get the same result.

Is there a way to copy it (or moving, I don't mind) keeping the same md5? Would it be a good idea to tar it?

Comment: Are we talking about md5 in general or md5sum specific?  md5sum only checks contents of the file so moving it should not alter it. Even renaming should not (the filename is not inside the file itself). Here is the source code: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/7c62dfbbcd3699efcbbadc9fb3aa14f23a123add/libiberty/md5.c#L135

Answer (score 3):

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is widely used as a quick way to see if a file has been unintentionally modified. The same data always has the same MD5 hash, so if you transfer a file and it has a different MD5 hash at the destination than at the source, then the file was corrupted.

This answer goes over the various common causes and solutions to this sort of problem. But if you want to try something [immediately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tl;dr), then yes: your idea of archiving the file with [`tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tar.1.html) may work. (See below for details.)

#### Check if the file was downloaded correctly in the first place.

First, it is best to check that the file was downloaded correctly in the first place. The website where you downloaded it may contain instructions for how to do this. If this is a script that calls [`md5sum`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/md5sum.1.html), or some such utility, to compute its own MD5 hash, and you are able to run the script on the machine where you download it, that is one way of testing it.

Without specific information about how you are downloading the file, it is difficult to know the most likely causes of corruption. With installers provided as shell scripts that contain binary data, sometimes a web server tells your browser an incorrect [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) for a file. I have had this problem myself, more than once, with `.sh` files I have downloaded from software vendors' websites. But I have no specific reason to think that is what is happening in your case.

A similar problem could be happening when you transfer the file between your two machines. If so, *that* problem is one you can solve easily.

#### Make sure to transfer the file between your machines the right way.

Second, you should examine *how* you are transferring the file from one machine to the other. Some installers provided as shell scripts contain binary data in a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells), and some protocols used to transfer files -- such as [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) -- have separate modes for [text files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) and [binary files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file). If a file contains binary data that is incorrectly interpreted as text while it is transferred, the destination file may be corrupted.

If you are using an old-style FTP client where you must manually set whether to transfer the file as text or binary, use binary mode anytime a file might contain binary data, including in this situation.

- To be sure you are sending it as a binary file in [`ftp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/netkit-ftp.1.html) or a similar utility, you can issue the `binary` command (at the `ftp>` prompt once you're connected and ready to transfer the file), you should be told `200 Type set to I`, and then you can issue the `put` command immediately afterward to send the file.

Many modern FTP clients automatically figure out whether to transfer a file as text or binary data by looking at how the file is named. Files with extensions like `.txt`, for example, may be sent as text. If the script is named in a way to indicate that it is a script -- for example, if it ends with `.sh`, as you seemed to indicate it does -- then such an ftp client may assume it consist solely of text, as most shell scripts do.

- If your ftp client -- or perhaps some other kind of program, depending on how you're sending the file -- were to examine the inside of the file itself, and not just its name, it would likely *still* make this mistake, since `.sh` files with binary here documents usually start with a significant quantity of well-formed text.

There are a few ways to solve that particular problem. I suggest using one of the following three solutions. If you are using a protocol that is not FTP but that has different ways to transfer a file based on its type, these methods should work for that, too.

- Tell your program to transfer the file as binary. For example, you could temporarily make it transfer *all* files as binary, or you could edit the whitelist of file extensions (`.sh`) or globs (`*.sh`) to remove the entry that causes it to treat this particular file as plain text.
- Archive or compress the file so that it is unambiguously binary data. **Using `tar`, as you suggested, it one way to do this.** Note that, if you are using an FTP client where you enter commands manually, and it defaults to text mode (which is a long-standing, traditional behavior for interactive command-line ftp clients), then this will probably not help. But for most ftp clients people uses these days, it should help.
- Use a different protocol. Specifically, use a protocol where files of different types aren't treated differently. For example, if you can transfer the file with [`sftp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sftp.1.html) or [`scp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/scp.1.html), that is not subject to this problem -- that always treats files as binary data, and it checks to make sure they're being sent correctly, too (though you can still have a file corrupted at the destination due to truncation).

  Many graphical FTP clients also support SFTP, though you must tell them you want that, which is often achieved by selecting SFTP in a menu or prefixing the destination hostname with `sftp://`.

#### Compressing or Archiving a File for Transfer

As you suggested, you can use [`tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tar.1.html). To put `script.sh` in a `tar` archive:

```
tar cf script.sh.tar script.sh
```

Then, at the destination:

```
tar xf script.sh.tar
```

**Alternatively**, you can compress it with [`gzip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip):

```
gzip -k script.sh
```

<sup>Without `-k`, `gzip` replaces `script.sh` with the compressed file `script.sh.gz`. So if you *want* the original file removed at the source, then you can simply omit `-k` and run `gzip script.sh` (or just delete the file afterwards).</sup>

Then, at the destination:

```
gunzip script.sh.gz
```

There are other compression methods, such as `bzip2` and `xz`, but since it doesn't matter how well (or even if) the file is compressed, you can stick with `gzip` (or use `tar`, as above).

#### It might even work to just rename the file.

Of course, if the problem is that your FTP client (or other program being used to transfer the file) is incorrectly inferring that the file is plain text based on it being named with a suffix like `.sh`, then it should be sufficient to *rename* the file.

However, if any other mechanism is being used to detect the file's type, then that would break -- furthermore, it could be confusing to have files lying around that are named in a way that could mislead you. I therefore consider the method of just renaming the file to be brittle, and I suggest you use one of the methods above instead. (They aren't any harder than renaming -- each method takes just a single command at the source, and another single command to undo it at the destination.)